# Change the look of site element on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, aspx

I want to change the look of "more options" button, which looks picture below

[image]

I have tried to find it in CSS and masterpage files but couldnt find it.

Where can i find it and change it to a word or an icon.

this is the url for the page

"/...domain/sites/SiteCollectionOne/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

Comment: You can find the icons under 

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
> Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

Their name are *ellipsis.11x11x32* and *ellipsis16x16x32* so what you could do would be to replace the existing ones with a image of your's that you name to for example *ellipsis16x16x32*.

This should be done on your web-front-end.

Comment: I have moved out the icones but the page still showing them,
i have even renamed them, but still no change on the page.
refreshed and deleted cookies .

Comment: Are you're site using the feature "minimal downloading strategy"? Also, clear your browser cache.